# KendoDropdown with disabled default option

Tags: javascript, drop-down-menu, kendo-ui

I`m filling a kendo dropdown with a function but I would like for the default value to be "Select Option" which you wont be able to select it back once you select another one.

```
function FillInDropDown(dataSet,ddID) {

    var dropDown = $(ddID);

    if (!dataSet.error) {
        var i;
        var values = [];

        // Apppend the other options on dataSet
        for (i = 0; i < dataSet.dropdownData.length; i++) {
            values.push(dataSet.dropdownData[i]);
        }

        // Clearing Values
        $(ddID).empty();


        $(ddID).kendoDropDownList({
            dataSource: [],
            animation: false
        });
        $(ddID).data("kendoDropDownList").dataSource.data(values);
        $(ddID).data("kendoDropDownList").value(values[0]);


    }
    else {
        simpleDialog.info(dataSet.ErrorMessage);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two alternatives that you can pursue:

1. After the user [picks a value](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist#events-change), remove the `optionLabel` item from the [`list`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist#fields-list) and [`refresh`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist#methods-refresh) it.
2. After the user picks a value, prevent the selection of the `optionLabel` item via the [`select`](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/dropdownlist#events-select) event.

You will need a [one-time handler](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/intro/widget-basics/events-and-methods#event-binding-after-initialization) for the `change` event of the DropDownList.

Here is an example for both options:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/remotedatasource">
    <style>html { font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; }</style>
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.914/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.914/styles/kendo.default.min.css" />

    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.914/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2016.3.914/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>

    <p>The optionLabel will be removed:</p>
    <input id="products1" />
    
    <p>The optionLabel selection will be prevented:</p>
    <input id="products2" />

    <script>
      $(function() {
        
        var settings = {
          optionLabel: "Select a product",
          dataTextField: "ProductName",
          dataValueField: "ProductID",
          dataSource: {
            transport: {
              read: {
                dataType: "jsonp",
                url: "//demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/service/Products",
              }
            }
          }
        };
        
        $("#products1").kendoDropDownList(settings);
        
        $("#products2").kendoDropDownList(settings);
        
        
        $("#products1").data("kendoDropDownList").one("change", function(e) {
     e.sender.list.find(".k-list-optionlabel").remove();
          e.sender.refresh();
        });
        
        $("#products2").data("kendoDropDownList").one("change", function(e) {
         e.sender.bind("select", function(j){
           if (j.dataItem.ProductID == "") {
              j.preventDefault();
            }
          });
        });
        
      });
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```